# mongodb atlas is not connect with frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend, mongodb-atlas

im trying to connect mongodb atlas with frontend to store candidate data in database but i am not able to connect with database and getting below error while runing my backend. the server is able to listen the port but does not connect the db so can you tell me where the problem in my code.

## server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

// connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE,{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => console.log('DB Connected'));

// import the Candidate model
const Candidate = require('./candidate');

// use middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// create a route for adding a candidate
app.post('/api/addcandidate', async (req, res) => {
  const { candidate_name, party_name, imageURL } = req.body;
  try {
    const candidate = new Candidate({
      candidate_name,
      party_name,
      imageURL
    });
    await candidate.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Candidate added successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to add candidate' });
  }
});

// start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

## error

```
Server listening on port 5000
C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:847
  const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One 
common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:847:32)
    at C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
    at C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\server.js:11:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-96s78iv-shard-00-00.1fwqsln.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-96s78iv-shard-00-00.1fwqsln.mongodb.net:27017',
        error: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 3.212.187.25:27017 closed
            at Connection.handleIssue (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:131:15)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:64:35)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at node:net:709:12
            at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:582:7),
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 263109128,
        lastWriteDate: null,
        opTime: null,
        type: 'Unknown',
        topologyVersion: undefined,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: []
      },
      'ac-96s78iv-shard-00-01.1fwqsln.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-96s78iv-shard-00-01.1fwqsln.mongodb.net:27017',
        error: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 3.212.158.17:27017 closed
            at Connection.handleIssue (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:131:15)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:64:35)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at node:net:709:12
            at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:582:7),
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 263108910,
        lastWriteDate: null,
        opTime: null,
        type: 'Unknown',
        topologyVersion: undefined,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: []
      },
      'ac-96s78iv-shard-00-02.1fwqsln.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-96s78iv-shard-00-02.1fwqsln.mongodb.net:27017',
        error: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 3.210.79.179:27017 closed
            at Connection.handleIssue (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:131:15)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heet\Desktop\PROGRAMS\add-candidate-main\add-candidate-main\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:64:35)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at node:net:709:12
            at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:582:7),
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 263108869,
        lastWriteDate: null,
        opTime: null,
        type: 'Unknown',
        topologyVersion: undefined,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: []
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: go to mongo db Atlus, check Network Access in menu then Add a global or current IP address. then try

Comment: i've try but didn't work

Comment: Have you deployed this code on the server? Mean it is not working in the server right?

Comment: yes its not working on server

Comment: OK, then contact your server provider, and share this Issue, they will unblock this Access.

Comment: okie,, um if you dont mind then can give me the support on google meet to solve this problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to connect, But if you have Configured IP Access. then it's a server issue, Sometime they block it because of security

Comment: Are you using proxy?